# octez on v16.1 fails to validate block BM9b59Z7Weyh (3272488)

Tags: node, error

octez on v16.1 fails to validate block: https://tzstats.com/BM9b59Z7Weyh7C2FmqTpqzsXc5naTD4eLPUspdvoSNPgunLa2to.

Node version v16.1 (docker digest `sha256:f7559b2e130d027b96e90cf2ccc516a7b79faeacc630a3a35180a8653d5a0c5d`)

```
Mar 30 15:07:30.481 - validator.block: precheck of block BM9b59Z7Weyh7C2FmqTpqzsXc5naTD4eLPUspdvoSNPgunLa2to failed,
Mar 30 15:07:30.481 - validator.block:   Request pushed on 2023-03-30T15:07:30.480-00:00, treated in 26.287us, completed in 340us:
Mar 30 15:07:30.481 - validator.block:   Invalid block BM9b59Z7Weyh
Mar 30 15:07:30.481 - validator.block:     Failed to validate the economic-protocol content of the block. More details in the trace.
Failed to send event: Error:
                        Lwt.Resolution_loop.Canceled

Mar 30 15:07:30.486 - validator.peer: worker crashed [validator-peer]:
Mar 30 15:07:30.486 - validator.peer:   Error:
Mar 30 15:07:30.486 - validator.peer:     Invalid block BM9b59Z7Weyh
Mar 30 15:07:30.486 - validator.peer:       Failed to validate the economic-protocol content of the block. More details in the trace.,
Mar 30 15:07:30.486 - validator.peer:     trace:
Mar 30 15:07:30.486 - validator.peer:     Inconsistent hash:
Mar 30 15:07:30.486 - validator.peer:       got: CoV5Jt6XuTygXQxfvZ6cxZbKfFrxw1UVdfVZQSKZyppz5T6tU3Tq
Mar 30 15:07:30.486 - validator.peer:       expected: CoVb3a17irE61jwUb2K8nbcwK3Hr5pRT6Jyx52cickEzSTsJH23b
Mar 30 15:07:30.486 - validator.peer:       Invalid block BM9b59Z7Weyh
Mar 30 15:07:30.486 - validator.peer:
```

Tried `octez-admin-client unmark invalid`

Calling

`octez-client rpc  get /chains/main/blocks/head/header`

Returns

```
{ "protocol": "PtMumbai2TmsJHNGRkD8v8YDbtao7BLUC3wjASn1inAKLFCjaH1",
  "chain_id": "NetXdQprcVkpaWU",
  "hash": "BMci2TTxpZ5HNi9Us3em3fYLmS9kHR6UgWVoxQY5aBRQiQ1Arh9",
  "level": 3272488, "proto": 16,
  "predecessor": "BMNGUgiaohfWcxoiPP8CihtL2Vmd5br8RpUL3tNUhW2XbmKTeUB",
  "timestamp": "2023-03-30T11:05:42Z", "validation_pass": 4,
  "operations_hash": "LLoaY2C9kyRJfiQfDkUJK5M2yPhCWgXV4x5nZ1HRgGwYiocThLmtn",
  "fitness": [ "02", "0031ef28", "", "fffffffe", "00000026" ],
  "context": "CoV5Jt6XuTygXQxfvZ6cxZbKfFrxw1UVdfVZQSKZyppz5T6tU3Tq",
  "payload_hash": "vh225MnaQCfLGMPei8khLkQW9Wf55ma35ejcz3MnX31YnoiGvh48",
  "payload_round": 38, "proof_of_work_nonce": "5977cc15d4730c00",
  "liquidity_baking_toggle_vote": "pass",
  "signature":
    "sigcDm6UB3rsxiCZShhyUvhRer6U56JDjKFDG9rCjhWCLhytNvFe9eqcA5X4NduXptsSy5qZaBhto8ri4t57LwF2dxwxWjXB" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. You have discovered a bug of the Octez node preventing it to validate reorgs in single-process mode. We have reproduced the bug and we are working on a fix. In the meantime, please run your node without the `--singleprocess` option.